# How to update the duplicates in array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

**Problem**

The array contains duplicate items and needs to be updated to a specific format

```
val a = Array(a,a,a,b,b,c,d)
val b = Array(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,c,d)
```

**Explanation**

The items in the array can be duplicated "n" times

1. a item in the list duplicated 3 times
2. b item in the list duplicated 2 times
3. c & d item in the list is duplicated 0 times OR NO duplicates

**Requirement**

For each item if duplicated, it is required to add an incremental number by item

**Result**

a is the initial input array

b is the expected output array

**Tried**

Fold left , fold and other options. It is not yielding the expected result. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Those are not **Arrays**, those are **Lists**. Anyways show us the code that you tried, not just saying `foldLeft`. Finally, I would suggest a simple tail-recursive solution which carries a **Map[A, Int]** as a state to compute the correct result.

Comment: You can try this way:
val arr1 = a.groupBy(identity) map { arr =>
  arr._2.zipWithIndex.collect { case (x, y) =>
    s"""$x${y + 1}"""
  }
}

arr1.toArray.flatten

Answer (score -1):

Scala provides lots of library functions. Like, there is distinct function. You can directly call it.

```
scala> val array = Array(1,2,3,2,1,4)
array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4)
scala> array.distinct
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: The question is not to remove the duplicate

Comment: @rakeshjayaram; Perhaps you should change the title of the question.